# Run method on browser back button click in Silverlight MVVM application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a dependency property, of type enum, keeping track of the currently displayed page on a Silverlight application. This works splendidly, until the user elects to press the browser back button, and is returned to the previous page of my Silverlight program. The dependency property, however, is not updated.

Is it possible to update this dependency property in my code, without the need for obscure JavaScript functions etc ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Silverlight plugin is reloaded when you press Back, then you need to find a way to pass the information.

One solution would be to store the value in Isolated Storage, then read it back when you're loaded again.